# Javascript Remove specific attribute from style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello i have started to learn Javascript and i was wondering if there is a way to remove a specific attribute from the style here is an example that explain what i mean

```
  <div id="divbrd" style="width:500px; height:350px; border:1px solid #000; box-shadow:10px 5px 10px #777;"></div>
```

this is a div tag with a style so if i want to remove the box-shadow from the style attribute how can i do this here is what i have done :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var   div_brd = document.getElementById("divbrd");
    div_brd.removeAttribute("style","box-shadow");
    </script>
```

correct me please ...
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var   div_brd = document.getElementById("divbrd");
div_brd.style.boxShadow = "none";
</script>
```

[Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/shaileshsavaliya/9wuudazh/)

In this fiddle there is box shadow on div but it's removing from js

Comment: I have tried it it will work for sure. div_brd.style.boxShadow = "none"; If its not working than i think you have to check your call. When you calling this code?

Comment: here it's working but on my text editor it's wont so the problem would be with mine text editor

Comment: Which text editor you are using. Can you create fiddle.

Comment: am using HTMLpad 2014 and some times visual studio 2010

Comment: finally its worked when i use the visual studio 2010 i have tried it on htmlpad 2014 and notepad++ and the regular notepad and it haven't thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 0):

just in case if you want to learn jquery also.

```
$('#divbrd').css("box-shadow", "");
```

Comment: i still beginner at the javascript so i don't know anything about jquery but thanks for helping

Comment: @Istanbouly welcome, jquery is nothing but a javascript library. without jquery, things are a bit more tedious nowadays..

Comment: i know that the jquery is a small library of javascript but i told you that am new in javascript so i still have to practice it more then go to jquery

Comment: @Istanbouly yep, it was just an offer. starting from pure js is the right way to learn. have fun

Answer (score 0):

this will remove the attribute

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var   div_brd = $("#divbrd");
div_brd.style.boxShadow = "none";
</script>
```

OR

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('#divbrd').css("box-shadow", "none");
    </script>
```

Comment: also no it's still appearing i have tried more than one text editor

Comment: then i think the problem is where you are putting your javascript . put it on in the head if it still not work let me know

Comment: yeah it's worked now but you know i can't mark more than one answer and i have already marked one